# wxPython - How to force UI refresh?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I've boiled my problem down to the example code shown in this post.  Note that I'm not calling app.MainLoop() because this isn't an interactive window; I want it to pop up at the beginning, show some progress bars while work happens, and disappear when complete.

My (limited) understanding of wxPython and wx.Yield() led me to believe that calling wx.Yield() after some UI work would flush those changes to the display.  That is not occurring -- when I run this script, there is a gray box where "Hello World" should be.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size=(400,400))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Hello World", (20,20))
        wx.Yield()


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, -1)
        self.frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True


def run():
    app = MyApp(redirect=False)
    import time; time.sleep(5)

run()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to be yielding or updating on a regular basis, so that when your OS/window manager sends repaint messages to your app, it can handle them. I am not 100% sure about wxPython as I haven't used it recently but I don't think you can do what you want without the main loop to handle the messages appropriately.

You might find something useful here about threading the main loop, however (as well as explanation of why the main loop is important): http://wiki.wxpython.org/MainLoopAsThread

Answer (score 0):

instead of wx.Yield()

just call self.Update()

Comment: hmmm guess your right... I dont know you may have to add a MainLoop and  you could just show modally and then onclose or whatever kill the wx.App ... not sure really

Answer (score 0):

Without the `MainLoop` no events will be fired and also `.Refresh` will not work.

I guess `wxSplashscreen` may be what you are looking for. Example: http://wiki.wxpython.org/SplashScreen

Answer (score 0):

Not that it will do the original poster any good after all this time but `wx.Yield()` would have done the job. It just needs to be in the right place as does the `self.Show()`
The following outputs a progress bar which gets updated.

```
import wx
import time
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size=(290,200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Hello World", (20,20))
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self.panel, -1, 50, pos=(20,50), size=(250, 20))
        self.Show()
        n = 0
        while n < 50:
            n = n+1
            self.gauge.SetValue(n)
            wx.Yield()
            time.sleep(1)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, -1)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

def run():
    app = MyApp()

run()
```